# Cannot open second form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to open second Form using below code. It's should be working. But something has happened to my project.

```
Form2 newForm = new Form2();
newForm.Show();
```

Using mentioned code shows an error [as image shows.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuCF5.png)
I have added second form(Form2). What should can be the problem?

Error: `The type or namespace name 'Form2' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Well the image seems to indicate an error (red squiggles).. what is the error?

Comment: You can point at the red error underline to get an error message. I guess you have not used Form2 in declare

Comment: @Esmaeli - Maybe they don't want a modal form? `Show()` is perfectly valid.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb you are right, I just deleted my comment!.

Comment: Here is error, Error: `The type or namespace name 'Form2' could not be found`

Comment: What is the namespace of both `Form1` and `Form2`? The error indicates that they are different and that you do not have a `using` statement in `Form1.cs`

Comment: @BrootsWaymb yes It should be namespace. namesapace is different.

Comment: Just right-click the Form2 in code, select 'Quick actions and refactoring' and add the missing namespace using

Comment: thanks everyone for the sup!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to make sure both are in the same namespace, or add a `using` statement in `Form1.cs`.

So you probably have something like:

```
namespace TestFormsApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 newForm = new Form2();
            newForm.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
namespace TestFormsApp_Different
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Either change the namespace of the two to be the same, or add a `using` to `Form1.cs` like so:

```
using TestFormsApp_Different

namespace TestFormsApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 newForm = new Form2();
            newForm.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

You'll have to decide which approach is more appropriate for you. Both make sense in different situations, but that is another topic.

Comment: Yup, both options work. OP doesn't **need** to add a using statement to Form1, but also doesn't **need** to make them the same namespace. Sometimes it just makes sense to do one or the other, depending on how everything is best organized.

Answer (score 0):

The Form2 is in different Namespace than Form1. You need to use the using directive.

Pseudo code

```
// 1.st file, where the Form1 is declared:

// Place the using directive
using A2;

namespace A1
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public void ShowForm2()
    {
      Form2 newForm = new Form2();
      newForm.Show();

      // It works without the using directive aswell, while using following:
      A2.Form2 newForm = new A2.Form2();
      newForm.Show();
    }
  }
}

// 2.nd file, where the Form2 is declared:
namespace A2
{
  public partial class Form2 : Form
  {
    // Anything..
  }
}
```

Comment: They don't need to add a using directive. It's just one approach. It may not be the proper one for their case.

Comment: @CodeStranger That's true. In my code, the other(not all possible) approach was demonstrated aswell. In any case, this question has several correct solutions.

Answer (score -3):

you can try to open the form2 in the event of the form1.

double click on form1 and the onload event Load(object sender, ...)

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.Show();
}
```

Comment: The code running in your event is the exact code that isn't working for OP.

Comment: The only difference is that OP's event is called `Form1_Load_1` which is perfectly valid, and can also happen when playing around with autogenerating events, and one gets double-generated. This doesn't solve anything.